# About using C# to load a package in a Mathematica .m file

Tags: graphics, .netlink

I tried to load my .m file in the following way;

```
MathKernel mathKernel1 = new MathKernel();
mathKernel1.AutoCloseLink = true; 
mathKernel1.GraphicsHeight = pictureBox1.Height;
mathKernel1.GraphicsWidth = pictureBox1.Width;
mathKernel1.CaptureGraphics = true;
mathKernel1.ResultFormat = MathKernel.ResultFormatType.StandardForm;
mathKernel1.Input = "Get[\"C:\\\\1.m\"]";
mathKernel1.Compute();
```

The result

```
Graphics = {System.Drawing.Image[0]}
```

is not an image.

1.Mathematica code , save 1.m file:

```
data0 = Import["C:\\1.xls", "Data"][[1 ;; All, 1 ;; 4]];
pdpx = data0[[1 ;; 1000, 1]];
ListPlot[pdpx]
```

2.c# code

```
mathKernel1.Input = "Get[\"C:\\\\1.m\"]";
```

Why are multiple instructions wrong? is not an image.

Comment: Does it work if you replace ParallelNeeds by Get ?

Comment: Before trying to do it through C#, try the command directly in Mathematica, and make sure it doesn't fail. This one will fail because the syntax is wrong: 1. `ParallelNeeds` takes a context, not a file name. It does not load a file. For that, use `Get` 2. File names must be quoted.

Comment: I have tried, or error, code posted on it

Comment: Does `mathKernel1.Input="Get[\"C:\\\\1.m\"]"` work?

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved. Is there an official document on this aspect?

Comment: multiple instructions wrong,"System.Drawing.Image" is no image.

Comment: As to the proper way to enter `"` in a string, it's documented in the tutorial [Strings and Characters (字符串和字符)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringsAndCharacters.html#11857), particularly _Special Characters in Strings (字符串中的特殊字符)_ section.

Comment: Why can't multiple instructions be executed in C#? Can Mathematica execute? The code has been written on it

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. Then, I know nothing about C#, but what if you modify the code in the package to `(data0 = Import["C:\\1.xls", "Data"][[1 ;; All, 1 ;; 4]];
pdpx = data0[[1 ;; 1000, 1]];
ListPlot[pdpx])` ?

Comment: Thank you!，I'm asking the others。：）